# Display page information echo print_r ($ results, true) in html

Tags: php, html, user-interface, whmcs

Can someone help me with a change to a php script that currently displays my information with echo print_r ($ results, true), I would like to make an html form that displays the information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSl0M.png)

I would like to make it look like this if possible
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN9dQ.png)

This is the full php page:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ads312s19h8c0tc/license.php?dl=0

Comment: Please include all code as formatted text in your question description, not as external links to files.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with Java... please make sure to use the correct tags

Comment: I tried to put all the code here but it is too long and I get an error, that's why I put an external limk

Comment: you dont need to put ALL the code for your project... just the code that matters for your question

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code

Line No : 296

```
echo '<textarea cols="100" rows="20">' . print_r($results, true) . '</textarea>';
```

**new code is here**

```
echo '<table border="1">';
 foreach($result as $k=>$v){    
    echo '<tr><td>'. $k .'</td><td>'. $v .'</td></tr>'; 
 }
echo "</table>";
```

[image: See img here]

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I tried your solution and unfortunately it does not display any information at all

Comment: send array of $result.

Comment: This is works, but the script normally takes some information about the license key, with the function. print_r all this information is displayed and differs depending on the license key

I can only add something static to your script when the license is active